# Filter DataTable Efficiently

Tags: c#, linq, filter, datatable, datarow

What's the most efficient way of filtering DataRows in a DataTable? I have a list of integers and want to retrieve all rows (and eventually create a DataTable from them) which match the integers in the list. I'm currently using the code below, but it's quite slow. Am I missing a more efficient way?

```
foreach (var i in integerlist)
{
     DataRow dr = (from row in originalDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                   where row.Field<int>("urlID") == i
                   select row).FirstOrDefault<DataRow>();

     if (dr!= null)
     {
          newDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
     }
}
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268993/select-rows-from-a-dataset-using-linq-where-the-list-of-rowsids-are-in-a-list i hope it will helps you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to try to do vice versa.

```
foreach (var row in originalDataTable)
{

    if(integerList.Contains( (int)row["urlID"]))
       newDataTable.ImportRow(row)
}
```

It makes even more sense if you have more rows in dataset then integers in your int collection.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code but had to change `newDataTable.Add(row)` to `newDataTable.Rows.Add(row)` because there was no `Add` method. When I ran it though, I got this error `This row already belongs to another table.`

Comment: Sorry, it's just a snippet. You'll have to call newDataTable.ImportRow(row)

Answer (score 1):

Hm... may be I'm missing something, but...

Woudn't be it easier just use [DataView](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/12-dataview-to-datatable-c-sharp.aspx) and apply a [RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx) for it ?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing...  Still, I think @Elastep's answer is more of a solution to the original problem.  Good point though!

Comment: o6tech: not clear what is benefit of the code you refer to. You can create a *new* DataTable from the filtered DataView, if you need. I, personally, doubt that OP *really needs* a new DataTable.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can use this. I do need a DataTable though, because it gets placed in a SQL Server database and I need the data in a DT format.

Answer (score 1):

you could try doing a join such as:

```
var resultSet = 
from row in originalDataTable.AsEnumerable()
join i in integerlist
on row.Field<int>("urlID") equals i
select row;
```

that should give you the full result set.
if you need a datatable you could do:

resultSet.CopyToDataTable();

Comment: I get a `expected contextual keywords equals` error on the `select`.

Comment: sorry had == instead of equals, should have checked syntax

Answer (score 0):

As @Tigran says you can use the dataview, check [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73kk32zz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on how to accomplish just that.

Basically you use a `DataView` to filter the data and the you call the `DataView.ToTable` method to get the new DataTable.